# position: -webkit-sticky works only uptill the height of the container within a flexbox child on Safari(12.1.1)

Tags: css, safari, flexbox, css-position, sticky

The `position: -webkit-sticky` makes my element sticky but only until we scroll up to the height of the container. Once we scroll pass the height of the container then the `sticky element` scrolls along with the page. This happens only in Safari(I am using version 12.1.1) and works well in both Chrome and Firefox.

I have tried fixes like using `self-align: flex-start`, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Here is the code

```
<div class="container">
  <aside class="left">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat similique doloremque laborum ad repellendus atque, ut porro, sunt accusantium temporibus quaerat illum quis consequatur, illo numquam et? Quasi, aut corporis.
    </p>
  </aside>

  <aside class="right">
    <h1 class="sticky">Sticky Header</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quam a ipsa voluptatibus quisquam est ex ea sit nisi, provident totam, fugit quos, nulla fugiat sunt earum odit. Ullam, recusandae.
      </li>
      <li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quam a ipsa voluptatibus quisquam est ex ea sit nisi, provident totam, fugit quos, nulla fugiat sunt earum odit. Ullam, recusandae.
      </li><li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quam a ipsa voluptatibus quisquam est ex ea sit nisi, provident totam, fugit quos, nulla fugiat sunt earum odit. Ullam, recusandae.
      </li><li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quam a ipsa voluptatibus quisquam est ex ea sit nisi, provident totam, fugit quos, nulla fugiat sunt earum odit. Ullam, recusandae.
      </li><li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quam a ipsa voluptatibus quisquam est ex ea sit nisi, provident totam, fugit quos, nulla fugiat sunt earum odit. Ullam, recusandae.
      </li><li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quam a ipsa voluptatibus quisquam est ex ea sit nisi, provident totam, fugit quos, nulla fugiat sunt earum odit. Ullam, recusandae.
      </li><li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quam a ipsa voluptatibus quisquam est ex ea sit nisi, provident totam, fugit quos, nulla fugiat sunt earum odit. Ullam, recusandae.
      </li><li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quam a ipsa voluptatibus quisquam est ex ea sit nisi, provident totam, fugit quos, nulla fugiat sunt earum odit. Ullam, recusandae.
      </li><li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quam a ipsa voluptatibus quisquam est ex ea sit nisi, provident totam, fugit quos, nulla fugiat sunt earum odit. Ullam, recusandae.
      </li><li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quam a ipsa voluptatibus quisquam est ex ea sit nisi, provident totam, fugit quos, nulla fugiat sunt earum odit. Ullam, recusandae.
      </li>
  </aside>

</div>
```

```
.container{
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}

.left{
  background: cyan;
}

.right{
  background: orange;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.sticky{
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  background: inherit;
}
```

Here is a link to a codepen.

https://codepen.io/AshwinLorung/pen/QXBRRb

Open this link in both Safari and Chrome/Firefox then you can see the difference in behaviour.

Comment: did you try `height: 100%;` on ``right` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried `height: 100%;` on `.right`, but no luck. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

For now I solved the problem by wrapping the sticky element and content inside a div. But I find this to be a hacky way. Still waiting for a proper solution.

```
<div class="container">
  <aside class="left">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat similique doloremque laborum ad repellendus atque, ut porro, sunt accusantium temporibus quaerat illum quis consequatur, illo numquam et? Quasi, aut corporis.
    </p>
  </aside>

  <aside class="right">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1 class="sticky">Sticky Header</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quam a ipsa voluptatibus quisquam est ex ea sit nisi, provident totam, fugit quos, nulla fugiat sunt earum odit. Ullam, recusandae.
        </li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quam a ipsa voluptatibus quisquam est ex ea sit nisi, provident totam, fugit quos, nulla fugiat sunt earum odit. Ullam, recusandae.
        </li><li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quam a ipsa voluptatibus quisquam est ex ea sit nisi, provident totam, fugit quos, nulla fugiat sunt earum odit. Ullam, recusandae.
        </li><li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quam a ipsa voluptatibus quisquam est ex ea sit nisi, provident totam, fugit quos, nulla fugiat sunt earum odit. Ullam, recusandae.
        </li><li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quam a ipsa voluptatibus quisquam est ex ea sit nisi, provident totam, fugit quos, nulla fugiat sunt earum odit. Ullam, recusandae.
        </li><li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quam a ipsa voluptatibus quisquam est ex ea sit nisi, provident totam, fugit quos, nulla fugiat sunt earum odit. Ullam, recusandae.
        </li><li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quam a ipsa voluptatibus quisquam est ex ea sit nisi, provident totam, fugit quos, nulla fugiat sunt earum odit. Ullam, recusandae.
        </li><li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quam a ipsa voluptatibus quisquam est ex ea sit nisi, provident totam, fugit quos, nulla fugiat sunt earum odit. Ullam, recusandae.
        </li><li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quam a ipsa voluptatibus quisquam est ex ea sit nisi, provident totam, fugit quos, nulla fugiat sunt earum odit. Ullam, recusandae.
        </li><li>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quam a ipsa voluptatibus quisquam est ex ea sit nisi, provident totam, fugit quos, nulla fugiat sunt earum odit. Ullam, recusandae.
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </aside>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

the h1 have a margin of 19.* px and it need to set 0. before it get sticky it need to scroll the margin. For the Height give it a height of 60px and line-height the same.

```
.sticky{
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    top: 0;
    background: inherit;
}
```

You got the same Answer on Facebook, so i dont know where you looking first.