# On Safari, if an ancestor has 'display: flex' and a descendent, 'position: sticky', it will only stick for the height of it's wrapper

Tags: html, css, flexbox, safari, sticky

As asked, but not answered here: [position: -webkit-sticky works only uptill the height of the container within a flexbox child on Safari(12.1.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56869420/position-webkit-sticky-works-only-uptill-the-height-of-the-container-within-a)

This is an ongoing issue and easily reproduced: https://jsfiddle.net/4ea9mdkn/

```css
.flexbox-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.overflow-box {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-wrapper">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="overflow-box">
    This is the regular box
    
    <div class="sticky">
    This is the sticky box
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  
  
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know of a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Safari doesn't support sticky yet. So you have to use position absolute. Here what I did with your css I hope it works.

```
   *{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.flexbox-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.regular {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
.sticky {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) but position: sticky has been 'fully' supported on all versions of Safari for a while now https://caniuse.com/css-sticky, plus, you can see it work partially in the example I gave

Comment: yes I did see that but in a point it started to disappear I am gonna look at it again. I hope we can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution. I tried on Safari and it is working. I find out that we shouldn't put any other element between sticky and its parent element. Also We shouldn't use overflow:hidden in the parent element.So here is the code.

```
.flexbox-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}
.regular {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```
<div class="flexbox-wrapper">
  <div class="mouse">
   <div class="sticky">
    This is the sticky box
  </div>
  <div class="regular">
    This is the regular box
    
   
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  
  
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis accusamus iure voluptatum, repellat illum excepturi saepe quam neque incidunt eius rerum voluptatem accusantium doloribus voluptas obcaecati nemo assumenda. Culpa, suscipit.</p>
  </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```